# Registering a custom PageHandlerFactory through code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, configuration, webforms

Using the Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure assembly we can register modules during the pre-application start phase, as follows:

```cs
DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(MyHttpModule));
```

Is it possible to register a custom `PageHandlerFactory` in ASP.NET web forms in code instead just like the example above with the module?

I currently wire this through code like this, but I find it too verbose (and it makes it much harder to create a quick start NuGet package, since I have to alter the web.config):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="CustomFactory" verb="*" path="*.aspx"
        type="Shared.CustomPageHandlerFactory, Shared"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this in code. In my particular situation however, the solution really was to register a HTTP module.

The HTTP module can upon initialization hook onto the [HttpApplication.PreRequestHandlerExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.prerequesthandlerexecute.aspx) event which is executed after the page handler factory created the Page, but before ASP.NET starts executing that page (and other handlers).

Here is an example of such a HTTP Module:

```
public class MyHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    void IHttpModule.Dispose() {
    }

    void IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) {
        context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += 
            this.PreRequestHandlerExecute;
    }

    private void PreRequestHandlerExecute(object s, EventArgs e) {
        IHttpHandler handler = 
            this.application.Context.CurrentHandler;

        // CurrentHandler can be null
        if (handler != null) {
            // TODO: Initialization here.
        }            
    }
}
```